# -[EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] Failing the second time on?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer, eaglcontext

I'm developing an iOS openGL ES application.

I'm doing the usual EAGLView / ES2Render stuff.

On startup, frambuffer creation succeeds, using the following code:

```
- (BOOL) createFramebuffers
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_mainContext];

    // [ A ] On-screen  

    // 1. Framebuffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_mainFramebuffer);
    bindFramebuffer(_mainFramebuffer);

    // 2. Color buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_mainColorbuffer);
    bindRenderbuffer(_mainColorbuffer);

    // Adjust size to view's layer:
    CAEAGLLayer* layer = (CAEAGLLayer*)[_view layer];

    if (![_mainContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer]) {
        // something went horribly wrong
        NSLog(@"-[ES2Renderer createFramebuffers]: Failed to obtain renderbuffer storage from layer!");
        return NO;
    }

    // Query new size:
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH,  &_backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_backingHeight);

    // Attach to color:
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _mainColorbuffer);

    // 3. Depth buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthBuffer);
    bindRenderbuffer(_depthBuffer);

    if (_useStencilBuffer) {
        // Depth + Stencil

        // Allocate storage:
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);

        // Attach to depth:
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthBuffer);

        // Attach to stencil:
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthBuffer);
    }
    else{
        // Depth only

        // Allocate storage:
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);

        // Attachto depth:
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthBuffer);

    }

    // 4. Validate the set:
    GLenum framebufferStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    if (framebufferStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        // Something went wrong!

        NSLog(@"-[ES2Renderer createFramebuffers]: Failed to make complete framebuffer object: %@",
              [self stringFromFramebufferStauts:framebufferStatus]);

        return NO;
    }

    // [ B ] Off-screen (Render-to-texture)

    // 1. Framebuffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_transFramebuffer);
    bindFramebuffer(_transFramebuffer);

    // 2. Depth buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_transDepthBuffer);
    bindRenderbuffer(_transDepthBuffer);

    if (_useStencilBuffer) {
        // Allocate storage:
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);

        // Attach to depth:
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _transDepthBuffer);

        // Attach to stencil:
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _transDepthBuffer);
    }
    else{
        // Allocate storage
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);

        // Attach to depth:
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _transDepthBuffer);
   }


    // 3. Textures (color buffers)

    GLuint* texPtrs[2] = {&_transTexture1, &_transTexture2};

    for (NSUInteger i=0; i < 2; i++) {

        GLuint* texPtr = texPtrs[i];

        // Create:
        glGenTextures(1, texPtr);

        // Bind:
        bindTexture2D(*texPtr);

        // Configure for pixel-aligned use:
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // Allocate storage:
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _backingWidth, _backingHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        // Attach:
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, *texPtr, 0);

        framebufferStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

        // Validate:
        if ( framebufferStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            // Something went wrong!

            NSLog(@"-[ES2Renderer createFramebuffers]: Failed to make complete framebuffer object: %@",
                  [self stringFromFramebufferStauts:framebufferStatus]);

            return NO;
        }
    }

    // Final State:

    bindFramebuffer(_mainFramebuffer);
    bindRenderbuffer(_mainColorbuffer);
    bindTexture2D(0);


    NSLog(@"-[ES2Renderer createFramebuffers] Succeeded.");
    return YES;
}
```

Soon after, `UIView`'s `-layoutSubviews` is called and I in turn execute `-resizeFromLayer:`:

```
- (BOOL) resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer
{
    // [ A ] On screen framebuffer

    bindFramebuffer(_mainFramebuffer);

    // 1. Resize color buffer
    bindRenderbuffer(_mainColorbuffer);

    if (![_mainContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer]) {
        // Something went wrong
        return NO; // <-- SECOND TIME ON, THIS HAPPENS
    }

    // Query new size:
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH,  &_backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_backingHeight);

    // 2. Resize depth buffer
    bindRenderbuffer(_depthBuffer);

    if (_useStencilBuffer) {
        // (Depth & Stencil)

        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);
    }
    else{
        // (Depth only)

        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);
    }

    // ...Validate:
    GLenum framebufferStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    if (framebufferStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        // Something went wrong!

        NSLog(@"-[ES2Renderer resizeFromLayer:]: Failed to make complete framebuffer object: %@",
              [self stringFromFramebufferStauts:glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)]);

        return NO;
    }

    // [ B ] Off screen (render-to-terxture) framebuffer

    bindFramebuffer(_transFramebuffer);

    // 1. Resize depth buffer

    bindRenderbuffer(_transDepthBuffer);

    if (_useStencilBuffer) {
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);
    }
    else{
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);        
    }


    // 2. Resize textures

    GLuint* texPtrs[2] = {&_transTexture1, &_transTexture2};

    for (NSUInteger i=0; i < 2; i++) {

        GLuint* texPtr = texPtrs[i];

        // Bind:
        bindTexture2D(*texPtr);

        // Configure for pixel-aligned use:
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // Allocate storage:
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _backingWidth, _backingHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        // Attach:
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, *texPtr, 0);


        // Validate:
        if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            // Something went wrong!
            NSString* statusString = [self stringFromFramebufferStauts:glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)];
            NSLog(@"-[ES2Renderer resizeFromLayer:]: Failed to make complete framebuffer object: %@", statusString);
            return NO;
        }
    }

    bindFramebuffer(_mainFramebuffer);
    bindRenderbuffer(_mainColorbuffer);


    // Pass new ortho projection to shaders
    [self initializeModelViewMatrix];
    [self initializeSpriteProgram];

    // Set new viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);

    NSLog(@"-[ES2Renderer resizeFromLayer:]: Succeeded.");

    return YES;
}
```

Nothing of what I'm doing is special. I have a separate framebuffer to render scene transitions, with two textures to attach to color, and depth.

The second time `-renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:` is called (`-layoutSubviews` -> `resizeFromLayer:`), it invariably fails (returns `NO`); Calling `glGetError()` right before that results in no error, but calling it right after returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. 
If I ignore this and proceed, `glGetRenderbufferParameteriv()` still gets me the right width and height (640 and 1136, respectively, on an iPhone 5), but `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` will return `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`.

Alternatively, I skipped the above `resizeFromLayer:` and replaced it with this:

```
- (BOOL) resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer
{
    [self destroyFramebuffers];

    return [self createFramebuffers];
}
```

...but the same error persists (`-renderStorage:fromDrawable:` fails; this time inside `-createFramebuffers`).

For now, I just return `YES` (my app only supports portrait, so no screen size change actually ever happens), but I really want to fix it because one day I'll need to support landscape, etc...

Comment: I recently encountered this problem, but only when running on an iOS 7 device (not simulator). Unfortunately I don't know what caused it, but restarting the device appeared to fix the problem. Very annoying though, and no guarantees that it won't happen again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *possible* reason that `renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:` is failing is that the `_mainContext` is not the current context at that time. Even though it may seem that no other context could have stolen the 'current' status, I recommend calling `[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_mainContext]` before any `gl` or `EAGL` code that operates on objects associated with that context (e.g. at the beginning of the `resizeFromLayer:` method).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible reason is that the size of your layer is too large. In addition make sure you are using a new framebuffer and renderbuffer each time. And you have destroyed your old ones before creating new ones.

You can delete them like this

```
if let displayFramebuffer = self.displayFramebuffer {
    var temporaryFramebuffer = displayFramebuffer
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &temporaryFramebuffer)
    self.displayFramebuffer = nil
}

if let displayRenderbuffer = self.displayRenderbuffer {
    var temporaryRenderbuffer = displayRenderbuffer
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &temporaryRenderbuffer)
    self.displayRenderbuffer = nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Josh Bernfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632921/4789773)'s answer inspired me. I check the size of `MyView` and the bounds of it is `CGRect.zero`. And the same with the `CAEAGLLayer`.
For me, init `MyView` with a nonzero `CGRect` solved the problem.

Hope it works for you.