# MKMapView crash on iPod when Re-enter in view

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, ipod, ios8.4

I use MKMapView it works fine on iPhone, iPad and simulators but in iPod it crash when i second time enter in the view(first time it work fine). I have tried this but it is not work for me:

```
-(void) backButtonAction    
 {  
  [_mapView setDelegate:nil];  
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
 }
```

When I try to execute the code on an iPod(go second time on view) .I get an error ( EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN,address=0x494f6055) )

Comment: Are all of your devices on the same iOS version?

Comment: @Goku No iPod on 8.3 and iPad on 8.1

Comment: OK. I thought it may have been a deprecation issue. Next, can you try to turn on a breakpoint for All Exceptions. You can do this in the break point pane and at the bottom there is a + symbol. Click this and Add Exception Breakpoint. Then try it again and see if it crashes on the offending line of code.

Comment: @Goku :The crash occured on the following thread: EAGLContext_renderbufferStorageFromDrawable(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned int, id<EAGLDrawable>) ()    libglInterpose.dylib`EAGLContext_renderbufferStorageFromDrawable(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned int, id<EAGLDrawable>):    0xc133f0 <+204>:  ldrex  r0, [r5]

Comment: wow. Not sure.  I did a quick search, does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326594/eaglcontext-renderbufferstoragefromdrawable-failing-the-second-time-on or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398961/exc-bad-access-at-lauch-for-eaglcontext-renderbufferstorage-fromdrawable-in-co

Comment: Actually i already try this and got solution but due to this didUpdateLocations method is not called and we are not able to get user location but for now we have only this solution.so thanks for your efforts and provide me this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this solution didUpdateUserLocation method is not called and you are not able to get user location internally from didUpdateUserLocation method but until Apple not fixes it.This is the only solution i got from the link [EXC_BAD_ACCESS at lauch for EAGLContext renderbufferStorage: fromDrawable: in Cocos2d app whie debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398961/exc-bad-access-at-lauch-for-eaglcontext-renderbufferstorage-fromdrawable-in-co)
 which i do and remove the crash.

In Xcode, go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme ... And for the Run Debug configuration (on left side) choose "Options" (on right side) and configure "GPU Frame Capture" as Disabled.